# Batch file to stop an exe

Tags: batch-file, task

I have a batch file with the folliwng code:

```
start C:\Users\Downloads\IG\IG\IG\bin\Debug\IG.exe
```

Which start a .exe application

I know want another batch file to stop this .exe

I have tried:

```
stop C:\Users\Downloads\IG\IG\IG\bin\Debug\IG.exe
```

and

```
taskkill /C:\Users\Downloads\IG\IG\IG\bin\Debug\IG.exe
```

but none of them  work

I know this is a simple task, and there is lots of information about it, but none of them work for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the name of the process that you want to kill, something like this will work:

```
taskkill /IM IG.exe
```

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx